# Get NPC to look at player with only head

Tags: animation, unreal-4

I'm wondering how to get an NPC to look at the player,
I have tried everything.

Find look at rotation changes depending on character rotation.

Here is a fun drawing if letters are too complicated.
[image]

Comment: How have you tried applying the [Look-At control](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/LookAt/index.html) for this purpose so far? How do the results differ from what you need?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

Ok, this works, forward vector from actor rotation.